# Centering a child UIView to its parent UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

I want to center a subview in the middle of its parent, I have looked at answers on SO but so far they have not helped me.  [This one specifically looks like it should work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11253622/94278), but doesn't.

Here is what I am doing

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    finalNumberCircle = [[CircleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    finalNumberCircle.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/2);
    finalNumberCircle.Color = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:finalNumberCircle];
}
```

I also tried the following:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGPoint translatedP = [self.view convertPoint:self.view.center fromView:self.view.superview];
    finalNumberCircle = [[CircleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100];
    finalNumberCircle.center = translatedP;
    [self.view addSubView:finalNumberCircle];
}
```

Here is how it looks (it's the grey circle)

[image]

Comment: When you say that it doesn't work, what does that mean? What do you get with the code you've tried? Is the view off center, and if so, how?

Comment: if none of these solutions work, may the problem is in [CircleView initWithFrame] code.

Comment: If none of the other solutions work, it may also be a problem with autolayout in iOS7.

Answer (score 1):

You have to move your code (2. example) from `viewDidLoad` to `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and it will work as suspected.

Before viewWillLayoutSubview is called your viewcontroller view bounds still can change.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should move half width to the left, and half height upwards:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    finalNumberCircle = [[CircleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.center.x-50, self.view.center.y-50, 100, 100]; 
    [self.view addSubView:finalNumberCircle];
}
```

But I would use something like:

```
#DEFINE CIRCLE_RADIUS    50

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    finalNumberCircle = [[CircleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.center.x-CIRCLE_RADIUS, self.view.center.y-CIRCLE_RADIUS, 2*CIRCLE_RADIUS, 2*CIRCLE_RADIUS]; 
    [self.view addSubView:finalNumberCircle];
}
```

I uploaded a demo https://github.com/luisespinoza/CenterViewTest

Answer (score 0):

convertPoint and related methods used when you want to convert coordinates from one view's coordinates to another, that's not your situation. You have to do something like:

```
finalNumberCircle = [[CircleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
finalNumberCircle.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/2);
[self.view addSubview:finalNumberCircle];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code...

```
[self.view addSubView:finalNumberCircle];

finalNumberCircle.frame=CGRectMake(finalNumberCircle.frame.origin.x+(self.view.frame.size.width/2-finalNumberCircle.center.x), finalNumberCircle.frame.origin.y+(self.view.frame.size.height/2-finalNumberCircle.center.y), finalNumberCircle.frame.size.width, finalNumberCircle.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility how to do it **(in case You need specific offset from sides)**. Just provide an offset from parent view sides, and it will auto-resize itself in center of parent view, and will also autoresize, in case parent view frame is changed.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGFloat mOffsetFromSide = 50;

    finalNumberCircle = [[CircleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x+mOffsetFromSide, self.view.bounds.origin.y+mOffsetFromSide, self.view.bounds.size.width-mOffsetFromSide*2, self.view.bounds.size.height-mOffsetFromSide*2];

    [finalNumberCircle setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];

    [self.view addSubView:finalNumberCircle];
}
```

In case You simply want to position view in it's parent view's center, leaving it's frame intact, then:

```
finalNumberCircle = [[CircleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];

finalNumberCircle.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/2);

[self.view addSubview:finalNumberCircle];
```

And yes - it is exact copy of Your provided code. It works on my side.

Maybe problem is with `CircleView` itself. Or You change it's frame later in code?

What happens if You change "`CircleView`"  to simply  `UIView` ?