# How to get the mid point of origin?

Tags: ios, objective-c, math, cgrect, cgfloat

How to get x1 &x2 origin?

```
self.spinner=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    float x1,x2,y1,y2;
    x1=self.view.frame.origin.x;
    x2=self.view.frame.origin.x;
    y1=self.view.frame.origin.y;
    y2=self.view.frame.origin.y;



    self.spinner.center=CGPointMake((x1+x2)/2,(y1+y2)/2);

     [self.spinner startAnimating];
     [self.view addSubview:self.spinner];
```

i have a spinner,i try to place a spinner in mid point ,i know the concept but how to get that x1&x2 origin really i have confused with this...

Comment: But `x1 == x2` and `y1 == y2` so there is no mid-point!

Comment: i am only know to get x origin ,how to get x2 origin @trojanfoe

Comment: You have the `x2` origin (which is the same as `x1`).  What is `x`?

Comment: sorry x1 i have mentioned ...@trojanfoe

Comment: It's the same as `x1`!

Comment: If you are trying to place the spinner at the center of its superview, [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11253622/375300).

Comment: @albertamg i misunderstood the x and y origin ,now i am clear with this concept and do by the standard thanks lot.....

Comment: @trojanfoe thanks lot to mention my wrong .....now i understood the origin concepts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not making point by

```
float x1,x2,y1,y2;
x1=self.view.frame.origin.x;
x2=self.view.frame.origin.x;
y1=self.view.frame.origin.y;
y2=self.view.frame.origin.y;
```

If you have to put indicator in the center of view,

```
self.spinner.center = self.view.center;
```

Comment: its working for me ,but how to get the origin,really i am like to know that ,i will accept your answer with in 2 minutes..

Comment: If you still want to get the center of the frame there is other way like,

`CGFloat midX = CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame);`

OR

`CGFloat midX = self.view.frame.width / 2.0;`

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Ohhh... sorry for last comment. I thought you want other way to calculate center. To calculate origin, you are doing right. `self.view.frame.origin.x;` is correct. But why you are taking it twice ? Its not making sense at all. Its like, 0+0/2.0 !!

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood how a rectangle is represented, your formula is based on using two corners but `NSRect` stores one corner, `origin`, and the width and height, `size` - see [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSRect). There are also convenience macros for calculating the various properties (max coord etc.) of a rectangle - see the docs as above.

However, for this particular task you might wish to use `UIView`'s `center` property, which will save you the math.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSRect
```

is created with

```
x,y,width & height
```

It's also has the centre property, which is a

```
CGPoint
```

.
To work it out manually,

```
center.x = origin.x + size.width/2.
```

.. And similarly for

```
center.y
```

.