# Centre animation on every screen size

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, animation, swift3

I created this animation in the centre of the screen on a 6-inch size view. How can I make sure the ratio stays the same when it adapts to let's say an iPhone 5s. I'm not talking about Auto-Layout or constraints. I added the animation code below. This works the way I want it in a 6-inch size, but again, When I resize everything for iPhone 5s, Everything looks fine, besides the animation itself. How can I fix this?

[[image: )]

iphone 6 animation screen above (This is the correct animation and how I want it to be position on the other screen size.)

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
    super.viewDidLoad() {
    circleAnimationView.frame = CGRect(x: 20.0, y: 90.0, width: 300, height: 300)
    self.view.addSubview(circleAnimationView)
    }
```

The animation code is on on seperate viewcontroller, here it is:

```
import UIKit

class CirlceAnimationView: UIView {

var replicatorLayer1 = CAReplicatorLayer()
var dot = CALayer()

// Animation starts running

func animation2() {

    // A layer that creates a specified number of copies of its sublayers (the source layer), each copy potentially having geometric, temporal, and color transformations applied to it.
    replicatorLayer1 = CAReplicatorLayer()

    // The layer’s bounds rectangle. Animatable.

    replicatorLayer1.bounds = self.bounds

    // The radius to use when drawing rounded corners for the layer’s background. Animatable.
    replicatorLayer1.cornerRadius = 10.0

    // The background color of the receiver. Animatable.
    replicatorLayer1.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.0).cgColor

    // The layer’s position in its superlayer’s coordinate space. Animatable.
    replicatorLayer1.position = self.center

    // calling this method creates an array for that property and adds the specified layer to it.
    self.layer.addSublayer(replicatorLayer1)


    // connectng the animation to the content

    // An object that manages image-based content and allows you to perform animations on that content
    dot = CALayer()

    // The layer’s bounds rectangle. Animatable.
    dot.bounds = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 12.0, height: 12.0)

    //The layer’s position in its superlayer’s coordinate space. Animatable.
    dot.position = CGPoint(x: 150.0, y: 40.0)

    //The background color of the receiver. Animatable.
    dot.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.2, alpha: 1.0).cgColor

    // The color of the layer’s border. Animatable.
    dot.borderColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor

    // The width of the layer’s border. Animatable.
    dot.borderWidth = 1.0

    //The radius to use when drawing rounded corners for the layer’s background. Animatable.
    dot.cornerRadius = 5.0


    //Appends the layer to the layer’s list of sublayers.
    replicatorLayer1.addSublayer(dot)

    // number of copies of layer is instanceCount

    let nrDots: Int = 1000

    //The number of copies to create, including the source layers.
    replicatorLayer1.instanceCount = nrDots

    // The basic type for floating-point scalar values in Core Graphics and related frameworks.
    let angle = CGFloat(2*M_PI) / CGFloat(nrDots)

    // The transform matrix applied to the previous instance to produce the current instance. Animatable.
    replicatorLayer1.instanceTransform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

    // Type used to represent elapsed time in seconds.
    let duration: CFTimeInterval = 10.0

    // animation capabilities for a layer property.

    // An object that provides basic, single-keyframe animation capabilities for a layer property.
    let shrink = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")

    // Defines the value the receiver uses to start interpolation.
    shrink.fromValue = 1.0

    // Defines the value the receiver uses to end interpolation.
    shrink.toValue = 0.1

    // Specifies the basic duration of the animation, in seconds.
    shrink.duration = duration

    // Determines the number of times the animation will repeat.
    shrink.repeatCount = Float.infinity

    // Add the specified animation object to the layer’s render tree.
    dot.add(shrink, forKey: "shrink")

    // Specifies the delay, in seconds, between replicated copies. Animatable.
    replicatorLayer1.instanceDelay = duration/Double(nrDots)

    // The transform applied to the layer’s contents. Animatable.
    dot.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.01, 0.01, 0.01)
   }
}
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251988/how-to-center-a-subview-of-uiview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a variable for device width :

```
var DEVICE_WIDTH = ""
```

Then in **ViewDidLoad** :

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width
print(screenWidth)

 // Detect the screen width (format purpose)
 switch screenWidth {

    case 320.0:
        DEVICE_WIDTH = "320"
    case 375.0:
        DEVICE_WIDTH = "375"
    case 414.0:
        DEVICE_WIDTH = "414"
    default:    //320.0
        DEVICE_WIDTH = "320"
    }
```

Then in **viewDidAppear** :

```
 switch DEVICE_WIDTH { 

    case "375": // 4/5
    // according to your need    
    circleAnimationView.frame = CGRect(x: 20.0, y: 90.0, width: 250, height: 250)

    case "414": //6    
    circleAnimationView.frame = CGRect(x: 20.0, y: 90.0, width: 300, height: 300)

    default: //6+ (414)    
    // according to your need    
    circleAnimationView.frame = CGRect(x: 20.0, y: 90.0, width: 350, height: 350)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
circleAnimationView.frame = CGRect(x: 20.0, y: 90.0, width: 300, height: 300)
```

Instead of hard coding those numbers, calculate them based on the superview bounds.

(But it would be better to position the circle animation view using auto layout.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. What would be the best way to go about using auto layout to sort this out? How could I make the animation an image view and the set the layout?