# Center UIImageView inside UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

So I have a `UIImageView` named `currentEventImage` that is inside an `UIView` `blurryBackGround`. I currently want to center the `UIImageView` in the `UIView`. Below is my current code

```
//Subviews will be added here
view.addSubview(blurryBackGround)
view.addSubview(currentEventImage)
view.addSubview(currentEventDate)

//Constraints will be added here
_ = blurryBackGround.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 17, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 330)
currentEventImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 330).isActive = true
currentEventImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blurryBackGround.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
currentEventImage.center = blurryBackGround.center
blurryBackGround.addSubview(currentEventImage)
```

Any idea how I would do that?

```
currentEventImage.center = blurryBackGround.convert(blurryBackGround.center, from: blurryBackGround.superview)
```

Tried this and it didn't work

Comment: have you checked this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/11253622/4637057

Comment: you mean the one from 2012 with the old syntax and depracated methods @VincentJoy

Comment: that did not work @VincentJoy

Comment: please Comment lines containing `heightAnchor` & `topAnchor` and retry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to try the following solution based on `centerXAnchor` and `centerYAnchor` (feel free to remove constraints on width/height):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var niceIcon:UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        niceIcon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        niceIcon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        niceIcon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        niceIcon.centerXAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: niceIcon.superview!.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        niceIcon.centerYAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: niceIcon.superview!.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

1. example of storyboard, raw icon misplaced and without any constraints.

[image]

2. on the simulator:

[image]

---

another solution (a bit more verbose) might be to add constraints, with the same constant, on `leftAnchor`, `rightAnchor`, `bottomAnchor`, `topAnchor`.  Such constant stands for the distance between the superview and the subview itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following example code:-

Here I have given the width and height of View as (200,400) and for UIImageView I have given the size as (50,50)

```
let whitView = UIView(frame:CGRect(self.view.frame.size.width/2-200/2,self.view.frame.size.height/2-400/2,200,400))
whitView.backgroundcolor = UIColor.white
view.addSubview(whitView)
let imgView = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(whitView.frame.size.width/2-50/2,whitView.frame.size.height/2-50/2,50,50))
imgView.image = UIImage(named: "abc.png")
whitView.addSubview(imgView)
```